# Image Recognition with the Hololens

Tags: c#, multithreading, image-processing, camera, augmented-reality

Goal: I want to develop an application that recognize images using the hololens camera.

The simplistic way of my question would be "how do I manage to do this?" ("too broad?", please keep on reading.

---

**What I have done (or what I do have) so far**

1)I have managed to develop a Hololens app that takes photos on command (gesture-but voice can be doable too) and raise an hologram with the photo. (so this question *is not* a duplicate of "how do I work with Hololens Photocapture)

2) I have already developed several working algorithms that deal with shapes and letter recognition, neural networks, image processing. They are implemented in C# and in C++ (but I can convert them to C# since that is the language that the hololens use)  (so this question *is not* a duplicate of "how do I program OCR" or "how to I process images" and *is not* too broad in that I don't specify what kind of image recognition I want: I am not asking that)

3)I read that when using PhotoCapture you can put the image into disk or memory but when using VideoCapture it only works to disk (not memory)

4) I have read about asynchronous processing to understand the difference with multithreading

---

**What I am asking (in more detail)**

So I am thinking that to do the Goal I will have to take photos continuously and process them. Is my assumption correct? or is there any other way?

If this is so, do I need to implement my image processing into a separate thread? ( I suppose so since it can take some time)- take into account that photocapture is asynchronous.

And also directly related to the speed issue, do I have to re-implement my algorithms using unsafe programming to handle directly pointers to the images in order to increase speed?

---

just in case this question gets labeled as "too many questions in one", let me rephrase the question in "I am thinking of solving the problem by continuously taking photos with Photocapture, take the results to a different thread where the image taken will be handled by unsafe pointers and processed  in order to increase speed-is this correct or is any other way?)

Any advice , pointer or useful recommendation will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have answers for all of your questions, but what I think is that you don't need to make your images processing in another thread since you are not having other processes running in the same thread, also I suggest you make your whole process by something like FIFO list ([check Queue class here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue(v=vs.110).aspx)) where you save the unprocessed captured images, and in the meantime you will keep processing the the first unprocessed images in the queue. This way you can handle the difference of the speed between the capturing task and the image processing task for each image instance without wasting any captured images and in the same time you will keep the the processing result in the same order of the captured photos.